# Does one connection could be hold by two thread at the same time in spring-jdbc?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

In this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/5c7aee7d38c3c2d37ae1abc61864736ba5a71c7e), the author states that:

> "After this change the storage
>   the engine used by the sequence table can be MyISAM or INNODB since the
>   sequences are allocated using a **new connection** without being
>   **affected by any other transactions** that might be in progress.
>   ".

Why should we create a new connection to start a transaction? I think that if one connection is not held by two thread at the same time, there would not be 'other transaction' on this connection. Could one connection behold by two threads at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why should we create a new connection to start a transaction?

Because there is no way around it. You must have established a connection with the database before you can query the database.

> Could one connection behold by two threads at the same time?

Yes, it [could](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/devguide/cdevconcepts23499.html). Especially if two threads are operating with different tables. Why not reuse the existing connection? In more modern frameworks you will find connection pools that have a pool of open connections open for any thread to use it. It is a better practice to have a pool of connections.

Comment: Sharing one connection by multiple threads although possible in theory, is a bad idea in practice. Avoid it where possible, and only do it if those threads carefully coordinate their activity (eg you don't want one thread to commit or rollback, while the other is still working fully expecting the transaction to continue).

Comment: @AlanSereb In this link, the author did a code optimization. The original code obtain the connection of the current thread, and the optimized code obtain a new connection. So I asked that could one connection be hold by two threads at the same time. If allowed, then as Mark Rottelveel stated, the code is not robust.If not, this optimization doesn't seem very useful.Through the explanation of yours, can I understand that because Spring can use different DataSource and  different connection allocation strategy, so there might be a strategy that allows threads to share connections, right?

Comment: @kongtianyi. Again, using connection between multiple threads is a bad idea. In the code provided the developer defaults to true (which means using different connection for a different thread), but leave another option in case somebody wants to do it otherwise.

Comment: @AlanSerebThe key point of my question is whether the threads in Spring can share the connection at the same time. If not, even if the author does not optimize, the code will still use the connection of the current thread and there will be no transaction conflict.From the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/devguide/cdevconcepts23499.html) you provided, there may be stratgy that allow connection be shared, so thank you for your answer.